# How to add sqlite3 to pipenv environment?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pipenv, google-ad-manager

I've recently switched from conda envs to pipenv.
Probably since then some Google AdManager Client code doesn't work anymore, instead showing resulting in the error "RuntimeError: sqlite3 module is required for the SqliteCache"

According to the traceback the error is caused by zeep which is used by google admanager client not finding sqlite3 which it uses for caching.

I instatiate the AdManager library like this:
`ad_manager_client = ad_manager.AdManagerClient.LoadFromStorage(path='./googleads.yaml')`

The error occurs on this line:
`report_job_id = report_downloader.WaitForReport(report_job)`

Why is sqlite3 not automatically part of my pipenv environment?
How can I add it?

UPDATE:
Result of pipenv shell followed by 'python -c "import sqlite3"':

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\klst\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\klst\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Comment: Are you running the code locally, or from GAE? According to this: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/issues/326#issuecomment-422411317 It looks like `sqlite3` is excluded when running in app engine, even though it's part of the python standard library.

Comment: I'm running it locally on a Windows machine

Comment: Can you run `pipenv shell` followed by `python -c "import sqlite3"`? I'm curious if there are errors when trying to import sqlite from the python being used by pipenv.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4332 the following solved the problem:

Copy file C:\Anaconda3\Libary\bin\sqlite3.dll to C:\Anaconda3\Dlls